# How to keep track of new logins?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

How can i know new user logged in? I want to create a bash script and when new user logged in, the script will perform some task. But how to watch new logins?

Comment: "_when new user logged in, the script will perform some task_" - why can't you call your program from the login scripts that are executed when a user logs in?

Comment: You mean .bashrc?

Comment: If it's just for you, then `.bash_profile` or `.profile` could work. But I was actually thinking of the system login scripts in `/etc`. Or even using `pam_exec` - a particular favourite of mine for certain situations

Comment: ...or `last` or pam_mkhomedir and check the ctime on the user's directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can see info about opened/closed sessions in the `/var/log/auth.log` file, if you have it.
Example output, after I switched user to root:

```
Apr  3 13:37:43 anonymoose su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by anon(uid=0)
```

How to watch a log file is another question in itself. For example, you could use the `tail` command periodically to find the last `n` lines of the `auth.log` file.

Comment: I dont have this file on my arch linux but have it on my ubuntu vm. How can i use it periodically? Actually i was trying to write a bash script, save all environment changes on a file and show it when a user logged in. Its possible to create cron job or some other way i dont know.

Comment: You can create a cronjob, or write a loop in your batch script that loops infinitely, and sleeps in between. Where do you want your file to be shown to the user? Because the best option might be to do all of this inside .bashrc or some other script executed at login, as mentioned in the comments.